# Global.asax event that has access to session state

Tags: asp.net, session-state, global-asax

I'm trying to access the session state in my global.asax for every request (page, documents, PDF, etc.). I know i can't do that in Application_BeginRequest, and i thought i could in Application_AcquireRequestState, but it won't works, which is strange because it works in another project.

So, i'm looking for an event in which i would always have access to the session state for every request.

Thanks

EDIT: @Mike

I tried doing this

```
Sub Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Session("test") = "test"
End Sub
```

But i still get errors as i don't have access to session state.

Answer (score 18):

The session gets loaded during Application_AcquireRequestState. Your safe bet is to build `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` and access it there.

---

Update: Not every request has a session state. You need to also check for null: `if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session != null)`.

Answer (score 9):

The initial `Request` will not have a `Session` tied to it. Thus, you need to check if `Session` is not `null`:

```
var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;

if(session != null) {
    /* ... do stuff ... */
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but if I can find something better, it would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9897194/56984) of [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140238/mike), here is a snippet with my working code in Global.asax:

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
             /* ... */
        }

        protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["isLogged"] != null && (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["isLogged"])
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = (LoginModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginModel"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the controller:

```
namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        /* ... */

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // Don't do this in production!
            if (model.Username == "me") {
                this.Session["isLogged"] = true;
                this.Session["LoginModel"] = model;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If HttpContext.Current IsNot Nothing AndAlso HttpContext.Current.Session IsNot Nothing Then
strError = HttpContext.Current.Session("trCustomerEmail")
End If
```