# Access Session In Global.asax Methods in MVC3 Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why HttpContext.Current.Session is null in Global.asax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185871/why-httpcontext-current-session-is-null-in-global-asax)

I am developing a MVC3 project (Razor).
I added a variable to my session in some Controller/Action (different per user).
I want to access this variable in `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method (global.asax).

This exception happened:

> Session state is not available in this context.

[Sample Project](https://rapidshare.com/files/2871787764/MVCSession.rar)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4185982/717732 and the question, too.

Comment: In that post :
 
@Torbjörn Hansson: Sometimes it's null, do you have any idea why that? – Homam Jul 17 '11 at 19:35

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit, see my post.

Answer (score 0):

For startes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185982/717732

The whole point is that `Session` is not available and simply will never be available at this point of time: and by 'time' I mean 'when this event is fired'.

Read the lifecycle for example at devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/

The Session object is prepared **much later**: during the `AcquireRequestState` event. This is the first 'time' when you can access the Session statebag and investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks quetzalcoatl,
This is true.

```
      try
        {                
            if (Session != null)
            {
                if (Session["mys"] != null)
                {
                    //Error
                    string s = HttpContext.Current.Session["mys"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: Have you just 'unaccepted' my answer? it's been over a year by now. What's wrong?